# TypeError: a is not a function in AngularJS on Modal Pop-up Issue

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrap-modal, angular-animations, bower-install

Whenever I am opening the Modal Pop-up, I am getting the TypeError on console and after that entire screen gets stuck/Freeze. I have to refresh the page every time after I open the Modal popup.

Error I am getting:

```
TypeError: a is not a function
    at d (angular-animate.js:2116)
    at angular-animate.js:2106
    at ia (angular-animate.js:3303)
    at Array.fn (angular-animate.js:3126)
    at c (angular-animate.js:405)
    at b (angular-animate.js:375)
    at Array.<anonymous> (angular-animate.js:3173)
    at m.$digest (angular.js:18431)
    at angular.js:18581
    at e (angular.js:6428)
```

I have searched that It might be because of the angular and angular-animate versions, I have updated and bower installed the angular and angular animate to the latest versions but still the problem persists.
Modal Pop-up is works fine some time, it opens and closes properly some times, but most of the times it causes screen freeze.

Could you guys please help me to find the solution of it.?

My bower.json:

```
"dependencies": {
    "oclazyload": "1.1.0",
    "jquery": "3.6.0",
    "jquery-ui": "1.10.4",
    "angular": "1.8.2",
    "angular-bootstrap": "2.5.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "1.0.11",
    "angular-ui-router-uib-modal": "0.0.11",
    "angular-toastr": "2.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "angular-cookies": "1.6.9",
    "ladda": "1.0.6",
    "angular-ladda": "0.4.3",
    "intl-tel-input": "16.1.0",
    "angular-ui-validate": "1.2.3",
    "angular-notify": "2.5.1",
    "bootstrap-sweetalert": "1.0.1",
    "moment": "2.20.1",
    "moment-timezone": "0.5.14",
    "angular-animate": "1.8.2",
    "datatables.net": "1.10.19",
    "datatables.net-buttons": "1.5.3",
    "angular-smart-table": "2.1.11",
    "bootstrap3-typeahead": "4.0.2",
    "angular-chart.js": "^1.1.1",
    "ng-table": "1.0.0",
    "crypto-js": "3.1.9",
    "pace": "1.0.2",
    "angular-ui-select2": "0.0.5",
    "angular-file-saver": "1.1.3",
    "angular-ui-grid": "4.6.1",
    "csv": "1.0.4",
    "jszip": "3.1.5",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "excelbuilder": "2.0.2"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "3.6.0",
    "angular": "1.8.2",
    "ladda": "1.0.6",
    "lodash": "4.17.10",
    "jszip": "3.1.5"
  }
```